# Merge doesn't notice change

Tags: git, git-extensions

Im using Git Extensions to merge one branch into another, there is a file which is different in both (new text at end). Branch A has the most up to date change but when I merge it into Branch B it says nothing to update.

So it doesn't flag it as a conflict or change it. What are the scenarios that could allow this?

Answer (score 0):

First, of course, you're using Git-Extensions, which may layer its own lard over whatever Git already does.  But I doubt that has anything to do with it, because `git merge` does not mean *make the files the same*.  If it did, why would we bother with branching and merging?  Running `git merge theirs` would throw away all your work and just take their code, so you'd never run `git merge theirs`.

Let's consider a simple case, of a repository with just *one file* in it.  That one file has some text in it:

```
This is a readme file.
It contains a speeling error.
It also says
that the first nuclear weapon
was developed by Abraham Lincoln
in order to subjugate Chile.
```

Now, suppose both you and Bob have access to (clones of) this repository.  You're an expert on history, so you fix the claim:

```
This is a readme file.
It contains a speeling error.
It also says
that the first nuclear weapon
was developed by Richard Nixon
in order to subjugate Namibia.
```

Meanwhile, Bob is a pretty good speller, but isn't a historian, so he just fixes the spelling error:

```
This is a readme file.
It contains a spelling error.
It also says
that the first nuclear weapon
was developed by Abraham Lincoln
in order to subjugate Chile.
```

If *you* merge *Bob's* work, you'll get the spelling-error fix.  You'll *retain your historical-accuracy "improvement"*.

All Git is doing here is taking the *common starting point*—the file with multiple errors in it—and seeing what you did (change the last two lines), and what Bob did (change the second line).  Git will *combine these changes*, if it can, and apply the combined changes to the *base* version, so that you retain both changes.

Now, if Bob also fixes the historical mistakes:

```
This is a readme file.
It contains a spelling error.
It also says
that the first nuclear weapon
was developed by Jeff Bezos
in order to destroy Earth.
```

*then* you'll get a merge conflict, because Bob touched the *same lines* you touched.  Git doesn't know which lines to use.

(You will also get a merge conflict if you and Bob change lines that simply abut, e.g., if the spelling error read `nukular` and Bob fixed only that one line, just before the "developed by" line.)

#### What you need to think about

What you need to consider here is this: *What is the common starting point for these files?*  In Git's terminology, which commit is the *merge base* of the two branch-tip commits that you are merging?  Any changes made since that *merge base* are the changes that Git will be considering.  You have changes since the merge base, and they have changes since the merge base; Git is going to combine "your changes" and "their changes", and apply the *combined* changes to that same base.